# How would i ask for application process completed succesfully

Tags: syntactic-analysis, conversation, telephone

We applied to International Revenue Service for obtaining ein for our new established USA based company, filled out and thereafter sent SS-4 form through fax and I need to check out on the phone whether the application process would complete successfully or not? However, I couldn't set out the right sentence to get an answer for this question from IRS representative? could you please help me out for this conversation.

Comment: You seem to have the answer embedded in your question: "*Would the application process complete successfully?*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

"I filled out an SS-4 form to obtain an EIN and faxed it on [date you sent it]. I would like to know if the application has been processed yet."

The representative may have been confused by you saying "would" because that can make it sound like you are asking something like "If I sent an application, would it then be processed."

Answer (score 0):

A common / idiomatic way of asking this is

> What is the status of my application?